# JBoss buildpath, project delete external jars

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I'm developing a web application in JBoss in Eclipse Luna using external jars. I have imported the jars clicking on Project => Properties => Build Path => Add External Jars. Because the web application will need to use those jars, i have placed them in the MyApp.war/WEB-INF/lib folder, so, when the webapp will be finished, i'm sure i can just export the .war folder and deploy it on another server.

1) The problem is that everytime i turn on my pc in the morning, the deployment process gives me a ClassNotFoundException. I see that the external jars are no longer in their place. As far as i know, i'm not using any plugin to manage dependencies (i'm a newbie on webapps)

EDIT: 
2) what i do is unpack my zip containing the jars again in the lib folder. Strangely, if i unpack them in a subfolder (for example, i place the jars in lib/httpcomponents/lib) JBoss cannot find the jars. What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try to inserting the external jar files in to jboss server lib directory (jboss\server\default\lib)

Comment: Ok, i'll try it and let you know tomorrow :)